# Small units: property initialization

Tags: c#

We're using Sigrid as our code analysis tool and one of the metrics it uses to measure code maintainability is the well-known "unit size". Units between 1-15 lines of code is deemed to add "no risk to maintainability".

I know it should never be a goal to stay within those limits for 100% of the code base, but even so it got me thinking. Object (property) initialization is a very common scenario you see in code, but are there any patterns you can use to initialize properties of an object while keeping the line count low?

Say, I have a "mapping" method that produces an object with input from another object:

```cs
public Person CreatePersonFromExternalSource(ExternalPerson extPerson)
{
    return new Person
    {
        FirstName = extPerson.Name.FirstName,
        LastName = extPerson.Name.LastName,
        AgeInDays = (DateTime.Today - extPerson.Birth).TotalDays,
        City = extPerson.Address.City,
        Street = extPerson.Address.StreetName,
        HouseNum = extPerson.Address.HouseNumber,
        DoorNum = extPerson.Address.DoorNumber,
        Gender = extPerson.Sex,
        Height = extPerson.Height,
        Weight = extPerson.Weight,
        HairColor = extPerson.Appearance.Hair.Color,
        // ...
    };
}
```

This method counts 16 lines of code starting from the open brace and not including the comment. You can imagine this type of object having additional properties.

**Is there any sensible way to keep a method like this at 15 lines or less?** Peferably without changing either the source or target datamodel (adding new intermediate could be ok).

The example here is C# but I think the problem applies to many languages.

---

**Why not change the datamodels?**

I know in many cases grouping properties into new subtypes is possible (such as `extPerson.Address` grouping address related properties) and could make it easier to split up the mapping into multiple methods. However, I don't always think that makes it more readable/maintainable. In some cases finding/naming an appropriate group can be very difficult and might become so arbitrary that it was clearly done just to lower the property count.

Comment: This [sounds like a job for **Software Engineering**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).  And otherwise does not meet the criteria for a **Code Review** posting.

Comment: Sandi Metz conference talk [All the Little Things](https://youtu.be/8bZh5LMaSmE?t=34).  The theme - If you want better apps, make smaller things.  She demonstrates the *natural* results, one of which is very short methods. Watch that video, then everything else of Sandi Metz-you will become a better Object Oriented programmer.  She is a most excellent teacher.

Comment: Ah! Found this:  [5 rules for OO programming](https://youtu.be/npOGOmkxuio?t=475) (Sandi Metz, of course).  A general "why" of "5 lines or less" for method length, for example,.

Comment: @radarbob Thanks, I'll take a look at those talks. I thought the question would fit under "Application of best practices and design pattern usage", but I'll try posting in SE instead.

Comment: @greybeard Sorry, that was a typo in the example. Fixed now.

Comment: @Xerillio just wondering, why not using something like `AutoMapper` to do the mapping? It would make things much easier to maintain.

Comment: There is nothing here for to apply "application of best practices." We are left with impressing ourselves with questionably relevant programming aphorisms and conjecture about imaginary code.

Comment: @iSR5 As a matter of fact we are as well, however, when it can't map by convention/member names, stringing together a lot of `ForMember` makes the unit equally long.

Comment: @Xerillio if you provide the original work or samples (if it's sensitive) to `AutoMapper` that shows the dilemma you've experienced, and led you to do your custom mapping (current work), then it would give a better view for us to review, and maybe provide a better ideas if possible.

Answer (score 2):

**One line of code**

```
public class Person {
  protected ExternalPerson personalData;

  protected string FirstName {get{return personalData.Name.FirstName;}}
  protected string LastName  {get{return personalData.Name.LastName;}}
  // etc.
  // properties and/or methods for public access to formatted
  // (protected) data

  public Person (ExternalPerson extPerson) {
    this.personalData ?? new ExternalPerson() : extPerson;
  }

} // Person
```

Comment: +1 for solving the unit size problem. However, I'd want to avoid the tight coupling with the external type, since now `Person` is only usable with one data source.

Comment: I was inferring the conceptual relationship.  I don't understand "only usable w/ one data source".  `ExternalPerson` is parameterized, the only difference I see is my example persists the object.  You can always make a new `Person`.